# PHP mySQL result to variable

Tags: php, mysql

I do not understand why this isn't working. I know it's something simple more than likely. I want the value from the 2nd query to be placed into `$newowner`  I am getting an array to string conversion error.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO owners (fname, lname) VALUES ('default', 'default')";
mysqli_query( $con, $query );
echo $query;
$query = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM owners";
$result = mysqli_query( $con, $query );
$newowner = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result );
echo $newowner;
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation on mysqli_fetch_assoc? You are getting an array to string conversion error because mysqli_fetch_assoc returns an associative array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc) returns an array. What you need to do is get the value out of the array, e.g.:

```
echo $newowner['MAX(id)'];
```

You can simplify it by assigning an alias to the column name, for example, in your query:

```
select max(ID) as MaxID from owners
```

and then you could use `echo $newowner['MaxID']`.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, `$newowner` is an array.  Try to add an alias to your query like:

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id FROM owners";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$newowner = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $newowner['max_id'];
```

to see how to access the value from an associative array or simply do to get the value in a numerically indexed fashion.

```
$newowner = mysqli_fetch($result);
echo $newowner[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your initial queries insert properly, `$newowner` is actually an array, so you can't just echo it out. You could show it like this:

```
print_r($newonwer);
```

But you would be better off using the following:

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(id) as ID FROM owners";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$newowner = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $newowner['ID'];
```